# Getting "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" when trying to redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a simple server which includes a database (mongodb). I've tried to check if I can insert data into it by making a simple form with 2 inputs and a send button like so:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Test</p>

    <form action="/attack-data" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="quote" name="quote">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I've tried to catch the sent data in my backend and then redirect to the homepage again. Sadly when I do that I get this error:

```
(node:11508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
    at C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Project\Server.js:47:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:11508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error 
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by 
rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process 
on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)       
(node:11508) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've red about the problem and I know that it happens when the server responses to the client more then once, The second time that my server responses is when I try to redirect back to the homepage inside of the post request. But I haven't managed to find where I send the first response.

The backend:

```
let express = require('express');
let mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/database";
let port = 9999;
let app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Connecting to the database (The database is created if it doesn't exist)
mongo.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}, function(error, client)
{
    if (error)
    {
        console.log("Error: Couldn't Create/Connect The Database");
        throw error;
    }
    console.log("Connection To The Database Has Been Established Successfully");
    const database = client.db('attack-patterns');
    const attackCollection = database.collection('temp');

    app.get('/', function(request, response)
    {
        response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    })

    app.post('/attack-data', function(request, response)
    {
        console.log(request.body);
        attackCollection.insertOne(request.body)
        .then(function(result)
        {
            console.log(result);
            return response.redirect('/');
        })
        .catch(function(error)
        {
            console.log("Error: Couldn't Insert Data To Database: " + error);
            return response.status(404).json({error});
        })
        response.end();
    });

    client.close();
});


// Listening to the port saved in the variable "port"
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server Is Listening To Port: " + port));
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's because you run `response.end()` immediately, before the database operation has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the route `/attack-data` you start a promise on the `attackCollection.insertOne` and you want to send the response in the `.then` or in `.catch`
BUT when start a promise, the code after is executed in the same time (start the promise in 
a thread) so your `response.end()` is executed before the ".then"

You can simply remove the `response.end()` and your code will work !

Comment: Ohhh I understand now, Thank you very much!

Comment: One thing I'd like to add: "start the promise in a thread" is not correct, the promise's callback gets pushed onto the microtask queue - and will be executed once it is ready. There's no second thread involved -> https://javascript.info/event-loop

Answer (score 1):

`response.end();` is executed before your `insertOne` promise has resolved, so once the handlers (`then/catch`) are executed, the response has already ended, i.e. the headers have already been sent. That's why you see the mentioned error.

You can simply remove the `response.end` statements as `response.redirect() and response.json()` already handle sending of the response.

Also you should not declare your route handlers inside the mongo-connect callback, instead define them outside of it.